# Python list keys randomly ordering them

Tags: python, dictionary, python-2.x

This is baffling me:

```
row = {'Item1':1, 'Item2':2, 'Item3':3}

fieldnames = list(row.keys())
print(list(row))

fieldnames.append('Item4')          
print(list(row))
```

Outputs

```
['Item3', 'Item1', 'Item2']
['Item3', 'Item1', 'Item2']
```

When run again:

```
['Item3', 'Item2', 'Item1']
['Item3', 'Item2', 'Item1']
```

What? Does keys() access the list randomly? Any better way of doing what I want? (i.e get the keys of a dict in the order they appear)

Comment: hashes are random hence the varying order.

Comment: It's not a List, a Dictionary doesn't have an order to it.

Comment: you may want to use OrderedDict.

Comment: What version of Python are you using? Using 3.x I get `['Item1', 'Item2', 'Item3']`

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867861/python-dictionary-how-to-keep-keys-values-in-same-order-as-declared

Answer (score -1):

As per the Python documentation:

`The keys() method of a dictionary object returns a list of all the keys used in the dictionary, in arbitrary order (if you want it sorted, just apply the sorted() function to it).`

https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html

Comment: I feel stupid. Thanks all